# Add Bone Constraint [Pole Target] have problem

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

First picture I use IK bone normally

[image]

next picture I use pole target but have problems can not rotation IK bone

Comment: could you please share your armature? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5943" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5943/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bend a bit your bone chain in *Edit* mode, and let it straight, so that it knows how to bend once in *Pose* mode, please tell me if I'm right.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for answer. This method works, but before this there was no problem. Therefore want to know the real cause.

Comment: before what? I think this (the straight bone chain) is the real cause, if it worked before it was just chance!

Comment: my last project is not problem.but i created new project last week.it's have problem this.